# RDP Session from Windows 10 into Ubuntu creates different user sessions on Ubuntu machine when new user log in

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, user-accounts, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu with a GUI. 
I am able to connect to it with standard RDP (remote desktop connection).
However, When a second user logins concurrently with same user credentials, instead of kicking me out, they connect successfully but a new user session is created instead of logging into the current one.

However, when User 1 logs out, user 2 can log into the original session. 
(I checked switching the different workspaces but to no avail)
TIA

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why is RDP creating a new user session everytime i log in?